# Liberty macOS installUtility with Java 9

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty

Running `bin/installUtility install javaee-7.0` on macOS with Oracle Java 9.0.1 fails. The only output is:

`javax/xml/bind/JAXBException`

When I temporarily switched to Java 8 (Zulu 8) it works fine.

What are required Java environments? Could not find this in the docs--only remember seeing 8 and higher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Liberty only supports Java 7 & 8 right now, we are working on adding support for Newer Java versions, but it isn’t complete at this time.

Comment: Liberty now supports new java versions.